# Сопоставить два dataframe по дате

Tags: python, pandas, дата, dataframe

Есть 2 датафрейма, в каждом есть строки с датой, но если в первой дат много, то во втором не все:

```
df1
0   2016-01-04  14
1   2016-01-05  17
2   2016-01-06  5
3   2016-01-07  9
4   2016-01-08  19

df2
2017-07-30 1
2017-04-30 1
2016-01-29 5
2016-01-29 1
```

Как видите, некоторых значений из df2 может не быть в df1
Нужно сопоставить значения df1 и df2 по дате, в new_df, в котором будет только строки из df2 даты, строки из df1 которых нет в df2 нужно удалить и наоборот - если нет в df1 строки из df2 - то и ладно

На выходе получаем:

```
 new_df
 2016-08-29 8 5
 2016-04-29 16 5
 2016-01-29 4 1
```

Варианты

```
new_df = df1[df1['Date'].isin(df2['Date'])]
```

не помогают

Все даты на всякий случай преобразованы

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
```

Comment: А что там за цифры кроме даты в new?

Comment: Вы можете привести такие примеры данных, чтобы было понятно откуда берутся данные в выходном DF? В ваших примерах данных - нет совпадений по дате...

Comment: @Vlad, метки python, pandas непосредственно относятся к вопросу, не нужно их убирать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос - вы можете использовать [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), который по умолчанию делает `"INNER JOIN"`:

Исходные DataFrame'ы:

```
In [174]: df1
Out[174]:
        date  val1
0 2016-08-29    14
1 2016-01-05    17
2 2016-01-06     5
3 2016-01-07     9
4 2016-01-29    19

In [175]: df2
Out[175]:
        date  val2
0 2017-07-30     1
1 2017-04-30     1
2 2016-01-29     5
3 2016-01-29     1
```

Решение:

```
In [176]: new_df = df2.merge(df1, on="date")
```

Результат:

```
In [177]: new_df
Out[177]:
        date  val2  val1
0 2016-01-29     5    19
1 2016-01-29     1    19
```